# Puppeteer extra plugin recaptcha fails to enter recaptcha solution

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, 2captcha

I am trying to solve a captcha with puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha.

When I run chrome with `headless = false` I can see that the recaptcha appears and gets solved.
The problem is, that after the captcha field disappears, nothing happens.

The logs of the puppeteer-extra plugin tell me that the captcha has been solved but the captcha id also appears in the "errors" array. These are the logs:

```
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha Initialized {
    visualFeedback: false,
    throwOnError: false,
    solveInViewportOnly: false,
    solveScoreBased: false,
    solveInactiveChallenges: false,
    provider: { id: '2captcha', token: 'myToken' }
}
puppeteer-extra plugin registered recaptcha
puppeteer-extra dependencies missing Set(16) {
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.app',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.csi',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.loadTimes',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.runtime',
    'stealth/evasions/defaultArgs',
    'stealth/evasions/iframe.contentWindow',
    'stealth/evasions/media.codecs',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.hardwareConcurrency',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.languages',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.permissions',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.plugins',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.webdriver',
    'stealth/evasions/sourceurl',
    'stealth/evasions/user-agent-override',
    'stealth/evasions/webgl.vendor',
    'stealth/evasions/window.outerdimensions'
}
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/chrome.app
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/chrome.csi
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/chrome.loadTimes
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/chrome.runtime
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/defaultArgs
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/iframe.contentWindow
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/media.codecs
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/navigator.hardwareConcurrency
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/navigator.languages
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/navigator.permissions
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/navigator.plugins
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/navigator.webdriver
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/sourceurl
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/user-agent-override
puppeteer-extra dependencies missing Set(3) {
    'stealth/evasions/webgl.vendor',
    'stealth/evasions/window.outerdimensions',
    'user-preferences'
}
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/webgl.vendor
puppeteer-extra plugin registered stealth/evasions/window.outerdimensions
puppeteer-extra plugin registered user-preferences
puppeteer-extra dependencies missing Set(1) { 'user-data-dir' }
puppeteer-extra plugin registered user-data-dir
puppeteer-extra ignoring dependency 'stealth/evasions/webgl.vendor', which has been required already.
puppeteer-extra ignoring dependency 'stealth/evasions/window.outerdimensions', which has been required already.
puppeteer-extra orderPlugins:before [
    'stealth',
    'recaptcha',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.app',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.csi',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.loadTimes',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.runtime',
    'stealth/evasions/defaultArgs',
    'stealth/evasions/iframe.contentWindow',
    'stealth/evasions/media.codecs',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.hardwareConcurrency',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.languages',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.permissions',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.plugins',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.webdriver',
    'stealth/evasions/sourceurl',
    'stealth/evasions/user-agent-override',
    'stealth/evasions/webgl.vendor',
    'stealth/evasions/window.outerdimensions',
    'user-preferences',
    'user-data-dir'
]
puppeteer-extra orderPlugins:after [
    'stealth',
    'recaptcha',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.app',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.csi',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.loadTimes',
    'stealth/evasions/chrome.runtime',
    'stealth/evasions/media.codecs',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.hardwareConcurrency',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.languages',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.permissions',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.plugins',
    'stealth/evasions/navigator.webdriver',
    'stealth/evasions/sourceurl',
    'stealth/evasions/user-agent-override',
    'stealth/evasions/webgl.vendor',
    'stealth/evasions/window.outerdimensions',
    'stealth/evasions/defaultArgs',
    'stealth/evasions/iframe.contentWindow',
    'user-preferences',
    'user-data-dir'
]
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha onPageCreated about:blank
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha solveRecaptchas
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha findRecaptchas
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha hasRecaptchaScriptTag true
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha waitForRecaptchaClient - start 2022-12-10T09:01:16.951Z
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha waitForRecaptchaClient - end 2022-12-10T09:01:17.095Z
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha hasHcaptchaScriptTag false
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha _generateContentScript recaptcha findRecaptchas undefined
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha _generateContentScript hcaptcha findRecaptchas undefined
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha Filter results: 0 of 1 captchas filtered from results.
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha findRecaptchas {
captchas: [
    {
        sitekey: '6LdkZisUAAAAACQ1YvSn_fsTXRLoNCsiYuoKyDH7',
        callback: 'GoogleRecaptchaResolved-cce0b13e-8713-49a2-acd5-26d83e190888',
        _vendor: 'recaptcha',
        id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
        s: null,
        widgetId: 0,
        display: [Object],
        url: 'myUrl',
        hasResponseElement: true,
        isEnterprise: false,
        isInViewport: true,
        isInvisible: true,
        _type: 'invisible',
        hasActiveChallengePopup: true,
        hasChallengeFrame: true
    }
],
filtered: [],
error: null
}
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha getRecaptchaSolutions { captchaNum: 1 }
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha getRecaptchaSolutions {
    solutions: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            provider: '2captcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            requestAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:17.177Z,
            providerCaptchaId: '72267878173',
            text: '03AEkXODAdsSHFnLWZfzpbpJu1AOGLPkPIxXUHInfXhViJLcn8rOn-DJ4jIKV0uIfcBhsOpOMUFyHFQuaLNNznqVee6cXE1b6U1X6pKiJnxOhuRIPQO5J0owKiv6KK_v_C6nKb3cqTrfvFmEFl4A1fOh-ZNg_agiICvdx2AUkcmOr8KJAp4dVdUhguEpgP-JnAthH8TBWt4hjne74flB3VUfopFvjAQMqDwmzCDXqYU53yxvh80hqjsVRCh2CAyfX0L9yN5Wseb_VTHdvJZh-nNUHdIt5NsNa9HVYT9NI2qsta-2Bq_xb-m8tnoAWD9TJbaoQ8YCUZ7o2wWUYJb8Iie5o8-YpfMu8vn07sHW1nz0EJFLvkahJ5sdgtCBMWbM54Up5fdRGZssQmroa23UgJiTOIHVa4G30hwj4tUB6c9NVT3OYDvZ61pjaMbMBvs05pOPzeMsaxRVW40yLvgnUYmCZNJv9k4WEIEL_Q8svmYf6kVnOJP5eZCIbSkX8-2gc-vbuZE4kAhrtj0d4qx5jgWvkWAr0MQxp6K6-NGnow9_L1QjdzbDavTWYdS-ubP54N2p4q677yhmtC8c8ZXWJAowOgrXNxVdX39RzMIJM1IZfhXC9-XEYwZ5i4JGa1uvK1dmreDPjWzBt0XHErgTPbXRjwy2c4lnKnar_oi-ZLPxMskZlJ-Kcobg7R_Nz-NkagYV2RDuKwP_37PiVFRV5P7awyrWK7S6GvL-Q0Pa4c3y63Kg8Vvl-PX77VdlIkI4knOGZDI9ppASqnQ2wCGYSwKM2DjRY29j69s_Sl8uDdug2KmL0F1spQoUE4yYPksKAI_yXFrKrmsBuwysGD65GyjLWdGmdMXnZ00ceURzeIprlclPeH_wrTQKmC4EeOGZh_FzBEwvU7GmeQrcKj7vMbSG8vrWVlJyiukPj2WPbJ2Dl_iV_Xtr3GyJDsjdItSTLA5fXgUQg_BRwpcTVbbrfiLJ-TnkW-W57VcgUt4fU-A5iwPm1P9BXq387UmFwa14IErSZYAhHcSjULR9IQiz32x9MppSvBL4oa1SHGwCklRRiQvqoaqQbG6stKVUt66_TaCRdAupJrTBFkP3wha0Y72kJt4Yu2FaOJ10HvOQXG0wzdDLBON6Mtk6ZaxQo-yvBZZnEmr85X2WNLNR2BJ_qb0qN5cFl-GA44Zu2aJkVvw6ND30OhGzQXEDaAL02YjCA1rUmTYEGuIIBb_aE_X6HJMQB356_BjDhoH861bh1t_jsW4MdqdHFnhaaCQBSiMrSkEks0qVIvrhAyAvyJV_qbKtdknfHUX6TaQ_-pbp7vZHM6uNA-NBkHJlE3T5AuqX6dCOBla_DB1oJ9X2_W9oF5ApH5uGBOy0NHsiSfnoBHxvXmKvYuVfnR1RM3Gt23xGsAdArGpBivuLG-vpzy7YlNYt_nrb8rw0FT0KG8YRPILjjn9TOWZI_bT37rGIAgiqRX0m0ayGL4Afj7ZW3nHmdlHGsx7x0AsYxoril3JIlXB5SFIkd0E7x_y7vTAbNoqHpqztjHkDPPEdWujnCgEhUasX5TMSSyQNsHONiw2rQmg93ZAV7WovNvQVo3b-4ppCjDFWRpjcpBsRZgG-WyJnpr3dtE_RIZarU7_2aDBnmWC46iVHfSQyw_u_tQPEImOTAKLVmHt_IqBoiCgTP5gPciycPqXu9gptlF8jHi9Zw-7pvW_DFWouo-9EM',
            responseAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:19.465Z,
            hasSolution: true,
            duration: 2.288
        }
    ],
    error: undefined
}
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha enterRecaptchaSolutions {
    solutions: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            provider: '2captcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            requestAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:17.177Z,
            providerCaptchaId: '72267878173',
            text: '03AEkXODAdsSHFnLWZfzpbpJu1AOGLPkPIxXUHInfXhViJLcn8rOn-DJ4jIKV0uIfcBhsOpOMUFyHFQuaLNNznqVee6cXE1b6U1X6pKiJnxOhuRIPQO5J0owKiv6KK_v_C6nKb3cqTrfvFmEFl4A1fOh-ZNg_agiICvdx2AUkcmOr8KJAp4dVdUhguEpgP-JnAthH8TBWt4hjne74flB3VUfopFvjAQMqDwmzCDXqYU53yxvh80hqjsVRCh2CAyfX0L9yN5Wseb_VTHdvJZh-nNUHdIt5NsNa9HVYT9NI2qsta-2Bq_xb-m8tnoAWD9TJbaoQ8YCUZ7o2wWUYJb8Iie5o8-YpfMu8vn07sHW1nz0EJFLvkahJ5sdgtCBMWbM54Up5fdRGZssQmroa23UgJiTOIHVa4G30hwj4tUB6c9NVT3OYDvZ61pjaMbMBvs05pOPzeMsaxRVW40yLvgnUYmCZNJv9k4WEIEL_Q8svmYf6kVnOJP5eZCIbSkX8-2gc-vbuZE4kAhrtj0d4qx5jgWvkWAr0MQxp6K6-NGnow9_L1QjdzbDavTWYdS-ubP54N2p4q677yhmtC8c8ZXWJAowOgrXNxVdX39RzMIJM1IZfhXC9-XEYwZ5i4JGa1uvK1dmreDPjWzBt0XHErgTPbXRjwy2c4lnKnar_oi-ZLPxMskZlJ-Kcobg7R_Nz-NkagYV2RDuKwP_37PiVFRV5P7awyrWK7S6GvL-Q0Pa4c3y63Kg8Vvl-PX77VdlIkI4knOGZDI9ppASqnQ2wCGYSwKM2DjRY29j69s_Sl8uDdug2KmL0F1spQoUE4yYPksKAI_yXFrKrmsBuwysGD65GyjLWdGmdMXnZ00ceURzeIprlclPeH_wrTQKmC4EeOGZh_FzBEwvU7GmeQrcKj7vMbSG8vrWVlJyiukPj2WPbJ2Dl_iV_Xtr3GyJDsjdItSTLA5fXgUQg_BRwpcTVbbrfiLJ-TnkW-W57VcgUt4fU-A5iwPm1P9BXq387UmFwa14IErSZYAhHcSjULR9IQiz32x9MppSvBL4oa1SHGwCklRRiQvqoaqQbG6stKVUt66_TaCRdAupJrTBFkP3wha0Y72kJt4Yu2FaOJ10HvOQXG0wzdDLBON6Mtk6ZaxQo-yvBZZnEmr85X2WNLNR2BJ_qb0qN5cFl-GA44Zu2aJkVvw6ND30OhGzQXEDaAL02YjCA1rUmTYEGuIIBb_aE_X6HJMQB356_BjDhoH861bh1t_jsW4MdqdHFnhaaCQBSiMrSkEks0qVIvrhAyAvyJV_qbKtdknfHUX6TaQ_-pbp7vZHM6uNA-NBkHJlE3T5AuqX6dCOBla_DB1oJ9X2_W9oF5ApH5uGBOy0NHsiSfnoBHxvXmKvYuVfnR1RM3Gt23xGsAdArGpBivuLG-vpzy7YlNYt_nrb8rw0FT0KG8YRPILjjn9TOWZI_bT37rGIAgiqRX0m0ayGL4Afj7ZW3nHmdlHGsx7x0AsYxoril3JIlXB5SFIkd0E7x_y7vTAbNoqHpqztjHkDPPEdWujnCgEhUasX5TMSSyQNsHONiw2rQmg93ZAV7WovNvQVo3b-4ppCjDFWRpjcpBsRZgG-WyJnpr3dtE_RIZarU7_2aDBnmWC46iVHfSQyw_u_tQPEImOTAKLVmHt_IqBoiCgTP5gPciycPqXu9gptlF8jHi9Zw-7pvW_DFWouo-9EM',
            responseAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:19.465Z,
            hasSolution: true,
            duration: 2.288
        }
    ]
}
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha _generateContentScript recaptcha enterRecaptchaSolutions {
    solutions: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            provider: '2captcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            requestAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:17.177Z,
            providerCaptchaId: '72267878173',
            text: '03AEkXODAdsSHFnLWZfzpbpJu1AOGLPkPIxXUHInfXhViJLcn8rOn-DJ4jIKV0uIfcBhsOpOMUFyHFQuaLNNznqVee6cXE1b6U1X6pKiJnxOhuRIPQO5J0owKiv6KK_v_C6nKb3cqTrfvFmEFl4A1fOh-ZNg_agiICvdx2AUkcmOr8KJAp4dVdUhguEpgP-JnAthH8TBWt4hjne74flB3VUfopFvjAQMqDwmzCDXqYU53yxvh80hqjsVRCh2CAyfX0L9yN5Wseb_VTHdvJZh-nNUHdIt5NsNa9HVYT9NI2qsta-2Bq_xb-m8tnoAWD9TJbaoQ8YCUZ7o2wWUYJb8Iie5o8-YpfMu8vn07sHW1nz0EJFLvkahJ5sdgtCBMWbM54Up5fdRGZssQmroa23UgJiTOIHVa4G30hwj4tUB6c9NVT3OYDvZ61pjaMbMBvs05pOPzeMsaxRVW40yLvgnUYmCZNJv9k4WEIEL_Q8svmYf6kVnOJP5eZCIbSkX8-2gc-vbuZE4kAhrtj0d4qx5jgWvkWAr0MQxp6K6-NGnow9_L1QjdzbDavTWYdS-ubP54N2p4q677yhmtC8c8ZXWJAowOgrXNxVdX39RzMIJM1IZfhXC9-XEYwZ5i4JGa1uvK1dmreDPjWzBt0XHErgTPbXRjwy2c4lnKnar_oi-ZLPxMskZlJ-Kcobg7R_Nz-NkagYV2RDuKwP_37PiVFRV5P7awyrWK7S6GvL-Q0Pa4c3y63Kg8Vvl-PX77VdlIkI4knOGZDI9ppASqnQ2wCGYSwKM2DjRY29j69s_Sl8uDdug2KmL0F1spQoUE4yYPksKAI_yXFrKrmsBuwysGD65GyjLWdGmdMXnZ00ceURzeIprlclPeH_wrTQKmC4EeOGZh_FzBEwvU7GmeQrcKj7vMbSG8vrWVlJyiukPj2WPbJ2Dl_iV_Xtr3GyJDsjdItSTLA5fXgUQg_BRwpcTVbbrfiLJ-TnkW-W57VcgUt4fU-A5iwPm1P9BXq387UmFwa14IErSZYAhHcSjULR9IQiz32x9MppSvBL4oa1SHGwCklRRiQvqoaqQbG6stKVUt66_TaCRdAupJrTBFkP3wha0Y72kJt4Yu2FaOJ10HvOQXG0wzdDLBON6Mtk6ZaxQo-yvBZZnEmr85X2WNLNR2BJ_qb0qN5cFl-GA44Zu2aJkVvw6ND30OhGzQXEDaAL02YjCA1rUmTYEGuIIBb_aE_X6HJMQB356_BjDhoH861bh1t_jsW4MdqdHFnhaaCQBSiMrSkEks0qVIvrhAyAvyJV_qbKtdknfHUX6TaQ_-pbp7vZHM6uNA-NBkHJlE3T5AuqX6dCOBla_DB1oJ9X2_W9oF5ApH5uGBOy0NHsiSfnoBHxvXmKvYuVfnR1RM3Gt23xGsAdArGpBivuLG-vpzy7YlNYt_nrb8rw0FT0KG8YRPILjjn9TOWZI_bT37rGIAgiqRX0m0ayGL4Afj7ZW3nHmdlHGsx7x0AsYxoril3JIlXB5SFIkd0E7x_y7vTAbNoqHpqztjHkDPPEdWujnCgEhUasX5TMSSyQNsHONiw2rQmg93ZAV7WovNvQVo3b-4ppCjDFWRpjcpBsRZgG-WyJnpr3dtE_RIZarU7_2aDBnmWC46iVHfSQyw_u_tQPEImOTAKLVmHt_IqBoiCgTP5gPciycPqXu9gptlF8jHi9Zw-7pvW_DFWouo-9EM',
            responseAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:19.465Z,
            hasSolution: true,
            duration: 2.288
        }
    ]
}
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha enterRecaptchaSolutions {
    solved: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            responseElement: true,
            responseCallback: false,
            error: {},
            isSolved: true,
            solvedAt: {}
        }
    ],
    error: {
        _vendor: 'recaptcha',
        id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
        responseElement: true,
        responseCallback: false,
        error: {},
        isSolved: true,
        solvedAt: {}
    }
}
puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha solveRecaptchas {
    captchas: [
        {
            sitekey: '6LdkZisUAAAAACQ1YvSn_fsTXRLoNCsiYuoKyDH7',
            callback: 'GoogleRecaptchaResolved-cce0b13e-8713-49a2-acd5-26d83e190888',
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            s: null,
            widgetId: 0,
            display: [Object],
            url: 'myUrl',
            hasResponseElement: true,
            isEnterprise: false,
            isInViewport: true,
            isInvisible: true,
            _type: 'invisible',
            hasActiveChallengePopup: true,
            hasChallengeFrame: true
        }
    ],
    filtered: [],
    solutions: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            provider: '2captcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            requestAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:17.177Z,
            providerCaptchaId: '72267878173',
            text: '03AEkXODAdsSHFnLWZfzpbpJu1AOGLPkPIxXUHInfXhViJLcn8rOn-DJ4jIKV0uIfcBhsOpOMUFyHFQuaLNNznqVee6cXE1b6U1X6pKiJnxOhuRIPQO5J0owKiv6KK_v_C6nKb3cqTrfvFmEFl4A1fOh-ZNg_agiICvdx2AUkcmOr8KJAp4dVdUhguEpgP-JnAthH8TBWt4hjne74flB3VUfopFvjAQMqDwmzCDXqYU53yxvh80hqjsVRCh2CAyfX0L9yN5Wseb_VTHdvJZh-nNUHdIt5NsNa9HVYT9NI2qsta-2Bq_xb-m8tnoAWD9TJbaoQ8YCUZ7o2wWUYJb8Iie5o8-YpfMu8vn07sHW1nz0EJFLvkahJ5sdgtCBMWbM54Up5fdRGZssQmroa23UgJiTOIHVa4G30hwj4tUB6c9NVT3OYDvZ61pjaMbMBvs05pOPzeMsaxRVW40yLvgnUYmCZNJv9k4WEIEL_Q8svmYf6kVnOJP5eZCIbSkX8-2gc-vbuZE4kAhrtj0d4qx5jgWvkWAr0MQxp6K6-NGnow9_L1QjdzbDavTWYdS-ubP54N2p4q677yhmtC8c8ZXWJAowOgrXNxVdX39RzMIJM1IZfhXC9-XEYwZ5i4JGa1uvK1dmreDPjWzBt0XHErgTPbXRjwy2c4lnKnar_oi-ZLPxMskZlJ-Kcobg7R_Nz-NkagYV2RDuKwP_37PiVFRV5P7awyrWK7S6GvL-Q0Pa4c3y63Kg8Vvl-PX77VdlIkI4knOGZDI9ppASqnQ2wCGYSwKM2DjRY29j69s_Sl8uDdug2KmL0F1spQoUE4yYPksKAI_yXFrKrmsBuwysGD65GyjLWdGmdMXnZ00ceURzeIprlclPeH_wrTQKmC4EeOGZh_FzBEwvU7GmeQrcKj7vMbSG8vrWVlJyiukPj2WPbJ2Dl_iV_Xtr3GyJDsjdItSTLA5fXgUQg_BRwpcTVbbrfiLJ-TnkW-W57VcgUt4fU-A5iwPm1P9BXq387UmFwa14IErSZYAhHcSjULR9IQiz32x9MppSvBL4oa1SHGwCklRRiQvqoaqQbG6stKVUt66_TaCRdAupJrTBFkP3wha0Y72kJt4Yu2FaOJ10HvOQXG0wzdDLBON6Mtk6ZaxQo-yvBZZnEmr85X2WNLNR2BJ_qb0qN5cFl-GA44Zu2aJkVvw6ND30OhGzQXEDaAL02YjCA1rUmTYEGuIIBb_aE_X6HJMQB356_BjDhoH861bh1t_jsW4MdqdHFnhaaCQBSiMrSkEks0qVIvrhAyAvyJV_qbKtdknfHUX6TaQ_-pbp7vZHM6uNA-NBkHJlE3T5AuqX6dCOBla_DB1oJ9X2_W9oF5ApH5uGBOy0NHsiSfnoBHxvXmKvYuVfnR1RM3Gt23xGsAdArGpBivuLG-vpzy7YlNYt_nrb8rw0FT0KG8YRPILjjn9TOWZI_bT37rGIAgiqRX0m0ayGL4Afj7ZW3nHmdlHGsx7x0AsYxoril3JIlXB5SFIkd0E7x_y7vTAbNoqHpqztjHkDPPEdWujnCgEhUasX5TMSSyQNsHONiw2rQmg93ZAV7WovNvQVo3b-4ppCjDFWRpjcpBsRZgG-WyJnpr3dtE_RIZarU7_2aDBnmWC46iVHfSQyw_u_tQPEImOTAKLVmHt_IqBoiCgTP5gPciycPqXu9gptlF8jHi9Zw-7pvW_DFWouo-9EM',
            responseAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:19.465Z,
            hasSolution: true,
            duration: 2.288
        }
    ],
    solved: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            responseElement: true,
            responseCallback: false,
            error: {},
            isSolved: true,
            solvedAt: {}
        }
    ],
    error: {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            responseElement: true,
            responseCallback: false,
            error: {},
            isSolved: true,
            solvedAt: {}
        }
    }
    captcharesult : {
    captchas: [
        {
            sitekey: '6LdkZisUAAAAACQ1YvSn_fsTXRLoNCsiYuoKyDH7',
            callback: 'GoogleRecaptchaResolved-cce0b13e-8713-49a2-acd5-26d83e190888',
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            s: null,
            widgetId: 0,
            display: [Object],
            url: 'myUrl',
            hasResponseElement: true,
            isEnterprise: false,
            isInViewport: true,
            isInvisible: true,
            _type: 'invisible',
            hasActiveChallengePopup: true,
            hasChallengeFrame: true
        }
    ],
    filtered: [],
    solutions: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            provider: '2captcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
            requestAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:17.177Z,
            providerCaptchaId: '72267878173',
            text: '03AEkXODAdsSHFnLWZfzpbpJu1AOGLPkPIxXUHInfXhViJLcn8rOn-DJ4jIKV0uIfcBhsOpOMUFyHFQuaLNNznqVee6cXE1b6U1X6pKiJnxOhuRIPQO5J0owKiv6KK_v_C6nKb3cqTrfvFmEFl4A1fOh-ZNg_agiICvdx2AUkcmOr8KJAp4dVdUhguEpgP-JnAthH8TBWt4hjne74flB3VUfopFvjAQMqDwmzCDXqYU53yxvh80hqjsVRCh2CAyfX0L9yN5Wseb_VTHdvJZh-nNUHdIt5NsNa9HVYT9NI2qsta-2Bq_xb-m8tnoAWD9TJbaoQ8YCUZ7o2wWUYJb8Iie5o8-YpfMu8vn07sHW1nz0EJFLvkahJ5sdgtCBMWbM54Up5fdRGZssQmroa23UgJiTOIHVa4G30hwj4tUB6c9NVT3OYDvZ61pjaMbMBvs05pOPzeMsaxRVW40yLvgnUYmCZNJv9k4WEIEL_Q8svmYf6kVnOJP5eZCIbSkX8-2gc-vbuZE4kAhrtj0d4qx5jgWvkWAr0MQxp6K6-NGnow9_L1QjdzbDavTWYdS-ubP54N2p4q677yhmtC8c8ZXWJAowOgrXNxVdX39RzMIJM1IZfhXC9-XEYwZ5i4JGa1uvK1dmreDPjWzBt0XHErgTPbXRjwy2c4lnKnar_oi-ZLPxMskZlJ-Kcobg7R_Nz-NkagYV2RDuKwP_37PiVFRV5P7awyrWK7S6GvL-Q0Pa4c3y63Kg8Vvl-PX77VdlIkI4knOGZDI9ppASqnQ2wCGYSwKM2DjRY29j69s_Sl8uDdug2KmL0F1spQoUE4yYPksKAI_yXFrKrmsBuwysGD65GyjLWdGmdMXnZ00ceURzeIprlclPeH_wrTQKmC4EeOGZh_FzBEwvU7GmeQrcKj7vMbSG8vrWVlJyiukPj2WPbJ2Dl_iV_Xtr3GyJDsjdItSTLA5fXgUQg_BRwpcTVbbrfiLJ-TnkW-W57VcgUt4fU-A5iwPm1P9BXq387UmFwa14IErSZYAhHcSjULR9IQiz32x9MppSvBL4oa1SHGwCklRRiQvqoaqQbG6stKVUt66_TaCRdAupJrTBFkP3wha0Y72kJt4Yu2FaOJ10HvOQXG0wzdDLBON6Mtk6ZaxQo-yvBZZnEmr85X2WNLNR2BJ_qb0qN5cFl-GA44Zu2aJkVvw6ND30OhGzQXEDaAL02YjCA1rUmTYEGuIIBb_aE_X6HJMQB356_BjDhoH861bh1t_jsW4MdqdHFnhaaCQBSiMrSkEks0qVIvrhAyAvyJV_qbKtdknfHUX6TaQ_-pbp7vZHM6uNA-NBkHJlE3T5AuqX6dCOBla_DB1oJ9X2_W9oF5ApH5uGBOy0NHsiSfnoBHxvXmKvYuVfnR1RM3Gt23xGsAdArGpBivuLG-vpzy7YlNYt_nrb8rw0FT0KG8YRPILjjn9TOWZI_bT37rGIAgiqRX0m0ayGL4Afj7ZW3nHmdlHGsx7x0AsYxoril3JIlXB5SFIkd0E7x_y7vTAbNoqHpqztjHkDPPEdWujnCgEhUasX5TMSSyQNsHONiw2rQmg93ZAV7WovNvQVo3b-4ppCjDFWRpjcpBsRZgG-WyJnpr3dtE_RIZarU7_2aDBnmWC46iVHfSQyw_u_tQPEImOTAKLVmHt_IqBoiCgTP5gPciycPqXu9gptlF8jHi9Zw-7pvW_DFWouo-9EM',
            responseAt: 2022-12-10T09:01:19.465Z,
            hasSolution: true,
            duration: 2.288
        }
    ],
    solved: [
        {
            _vendor: 'recaptcha',
            id: 'za5qgnk00ldj', 
            responseElement: true,
            responseCallback: false,
            error: {},
            isSolved: true,
            solvedAt: {}
        }
    ],
    error: {
        _vendor: 'recaptcha',
        id: 'za5qgnk00ldj',
        responseElement: true,
        responseCallback: false,
        error: {},
        isSolved: true,
        solvedAt: {}
    }
}
```

Any reasons why entering the solution might fail?